# "requireInteraction" option for Notification, not working on chrome 68

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

The "requireInteraction" option for Notification (in JS code) is not working with this chrome 68. It just stays a few seconds and moves to the windows 10 notification tray. After that clicking on the notification doesn't open the target page. How to fix this?

Comment: write your own browser? seriously though, every second chrome update recently has been a pain in the butt with seemingly undocumented changes in behaviour

Comment: perhpaps because `Google Chrome 68 to now use Windows 10 Native Notifications` and the room full of infinite monkeys that develop chrome clearly messed up - not really a programming question though, is it - I guess if there's some sort of workaround in the browser, but I doubt it - best to let the monkeys do their work